# ComCtl32.dll Version 6 with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, com, balloon

I'm trying to implement a balloon tip. By following the instructions on this page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760252%28VS.85%29.aspx

I managed to implement the balloon, but the balloon is not using the appropriate theme under Win7. I read somewhere else that for the balloon to use the right visual style, ComCtl32.dll Version 6 must be used.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997646.aspx

Now, my development platform is Qt. Is there any way to tell Qt to use ComCtl32.dll Version 6? Or am I forced to use Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've [blogged about this](http://qtcreator.blogspot.com/2009/10/xp-style-common-dialogs.html).

Comment: Thank you! Simple and effective.

Answer (score 3):

In order to use you need a manifest file (check your second link for the one needed). What visual studio does automatically is add such file as a resource file.

In any case if you have an Application.exe you can provide an external manifest named Application.exe.manifest in the same folder, and windows should load it.

If you have installed windows sdk (free download from microsoft) you can use mt.exe provided by it to [embed a manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235591%28VS.80%29.aspx). Also there are [other ways](http://cournape.wordpress.com/2008/09/02/how-to-embed-a-manifest-into-a-dll-with-mingw-tools-only/) for doing this with tools provided by mingw.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use Qt, why don't you use a [`QToolTip`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qtooltip.html)?

Comment: QToolTip does not have as much functionality as TOOLINFO. TOOLINFO can have icons, you can change the background color, you can give it a "close" button, make it look like a balloon and change the tip position. None of this can be done with a QToolTip.